# Combining two variables from the same column together using R

Tags: r, dataframe

The current dataset I am working with has a JobRole column. It came with Admin and Administrative. I want to combine these two data together as one new variable called Administrative2. I would like to see how many years each role has been with their current manager. But because my data has admin and administrative, I'd like that to be one variable. Could you please review my code and advise how I can do that? Thank you.

```
avg_yrs <- barplot_data %>% 
  group_by(Gender, JobRole, Department) %>% 
  summarise(averageyrs = mean(YearsWithCurrManager))
```

Comment: If you remove JobRole from your group_by() you will get the mean for either JobRole

Comment: @SusanSwitzer, sorry for not clarifying. I'd like to create a new variable with both Admin and Administrative combined. There are a lot of other columns of data so I want this to be all categorized the same. For the average, I want to see the total average for all the values assigned to Admin and Administrative together.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this problem by creating a new column using mutate() and case_when().This allowed me to group Administrative and Admin together, and kept the other roles as is.

```
Updated_data <- emp_attr %>% 
  mutate(NewJobRole = case_when(
    JobRole == "Admin" | JobRole == "Administrative" ~ "Admin",
    JobRole == "Nurse" ~ "Nurse",
    JobRole == "Other" ~ "Other",
    JobRole == "Therapist" ~ "Therapist"
  ))
```